# SnapLogic - SharePoint Online - Upload File Issue HTTP Response Code:501; Response Message: Internal Server Error. Reason: notSupported

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, snaplogic

As part of a SnapLogic pipeline I am trying to upload a file read from S3 to SharePoint using the `SharePoint Online - Upload File` Snap.

I am getting the following error:

> HTTP Response Code:501; Response Message: Internal Server Error.
>
> Resolution: Server error! Contact support
>
> Reason: notSupported

The 3 parameters are correct as they work fine when using the `SharePoint Online - Copy Item` Snap as well as the account used, this is the same and works with the copy snap.

The account has the following OAuth2 properties:

auth endpoint :
`https://login.microsoftonline.com/XXX.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize`

token endpoint: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/XXX.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token`

token endpoint config:

`response _type = code`

`scope = scope=Files.Read Files.Read.All Files.ReadWrite offline_access Files.ReadWrite.All Files.ReadWrite.AppFolder Files.ReadWrite.Selected User.Read`